# Control selected value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down which is populated automatically depending on another drop down selected item.

I use listbox1.val to determine the selected value.
However, when i try to get the selected value of the second list box, the value is returned as a block of code.

This is where my second drop down is populated:

```
else if (el.val() === "West") {
    $("#drpArea").append("<option value='Barry'>Barry</option>");
    $("#drpArea").append("<option value='Cardiff'>Cardiff</option>");
    $("#drpArea").append("<option value='Pembroke'>Pembroke</option>");
    $("#drpArea").append("<option value='Swansea'>Swansea</option>");

}
```

The list box populates as expected. However then when i call:
`$("#drpArea :selected").val` it returns a block of code, not the selected value.

I have also tried `$("#drpArea :selected").val.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `option:selected` and use `.val()` to get value

```
$("#drpArea option:selected").val() // it returns selected value
$("#drpArea option:selected").text() // it returns selected option text
$("#drpArea").val() // it returns selected value
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/90/)

Comment: Even `$("#drpArea").val()` will return selected value

Comment: I had tried `$("#drpArea option:selected").val` and it still returned code. However stupidly i missed the brackets on the end. using `$("#drpArea option:selected").val()` works thanks!

Comment: @DNKROZ Glad to help you. Satpal :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `val` is a function, not a property, so you have to call it with `()`.

Also, you don't need `option:selected`. The value of a `select` is the value of the selected option. So use:

```
$("#drpArea").val();
```

Comment: Yep that makes sense, silly mistake. This answer explains the exact problem. Thanks